# iPhone Dies with 80% Battery Remaining

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, power

My iPhone 5 runs out of power very quickly. First it was 50%. Then it was 60%, then 70%, and now 80%. At 80%, the phone will shut down like it would when the power gets to 0%. When it powers back on, it says 80%. It's almost like the limit of when to shut the phone off was, and still is getting to a higher percentage.

However, the phone is unusable. Not only does it run out of power quickly, it also drains power at a ridiculous rate. In half an hour, with wifi enabled and the screen off, it takes about half an hour to turn off. When I'm using it, it takes 10-15 minutes after a full charge to die. What's the cause of this issue, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The way you phrased the question, it is unclear what you are asking. It sounds like a bad battery. Take it into an Apple Store or Apple authorized service provider and see if they can fix the problem or replace the battery.

Comment: If it's a 5, it's at least 3.5 to 4 years old, your battery is likely at End of life and needs to be replaced.  They will not recharge forever.

Comment: It's the battery's fault! See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the iPhone 6s has a service plan - reduced cost replacement<sup>1</sup> for having an issue where the battery reaches an end-of-life state after around a year of use (causing the battery to die at ~30%), older iPhones normally reach this state when their batteries grow old and tired (lithium-ion batteries can only be recharged so many times before they become unable to hold most of the original charge). Your iPhone 5 has a 3-3.5-year-old battery<sup>2</sup>, and thus it's the battery's fault that the phone is dying so quickly.

The only fix is to replace your iPhone's battery, something you can safely attempt yourself [following this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQqPm3LmwV4) or bring your phone to the Apple Store to have them do it (cost is usually 80-100 dollars without AppleCare).

<sup>1</sup> The battery malfunctions are blamed on a manufacturer leaving the batteries exposed to ambient air too long; note that it is *not* a safety issue, merely a convenience issue. Recall information [here](https://www.apple.com/support/iphone6s-unexpectedshutdown/).

<sup>2</sup> Based on a release date of September 2014.

**tl;dr:** It's the old battery's fault, bring it to an Apple Store and get them to replace the battery to fix the issue.